# integral equality assumptions

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I would like to prove the following equality

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 v(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}dxdy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial^2 v(x,y)}{\partial x^2}dxdy$$

What is known that all above derivatives exist, u has compact support and the derivatives of v are bounded.

What the least needs to be assumed to be able to prove the equality? I would like to avert the higher derivatives of at least one of the functions (preferably v).

Answer (score 0):

Formally,
$$\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x\partial y}dxdy=\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\intop_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x\partial y}dy\right]dx
 $$
 $$=\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\right]_{y\in\mathbb{R}}dx-\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\intop_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial^{3}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}dy\right]dx
 $$
 $$=\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\right]_{y\in\mathbb{R}}dx-\intop_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial^{3}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}dx\right]dy
 $$
 $$=\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\right]_{y\in\mathbb{R}}dx-\intop_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\right]_{x\in\mathbb{R}}dy+\intop_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial^{2}v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x^{2}}dx\right]dy
 $$
 $$=\intop_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x^{2}}\frac{\partial v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\right]_{y\in\mathbb{R}}dx-\intop_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\left[\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y\partial x}\frac{\partial v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x}\right]_{x\in\mathbb{R}}dy+\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{\partial^{2}v\left(x,y\right)}{\partial x^{2}}dxdy.
 $$

I used Fubini theorem (to permute integrals), integrations by part and Schwarz theorem (to permute partial derivatives). Now you must check that it was allowed.

Comment: Yes that's the way to prove this but you assume that $\frac{\partial^{3}u\left(x,y\right)}{\partial y \partial x^2}$ exists for all $(x,y)$. Can you do it with any weaker assumptions on differentiability?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a counter example if the third derivative does not exists almost everywhere, please check it to see if I did not make any mistake :

For all $\left(x,y\right)\in\left[0,1\right]\times\left[-1,1\right]$
 , let be$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(x,y\right)=-x\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4}}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right).$$
 Let us remark that the serie is uniformly convergent : for all $y\in\left[-1,1\right]$
 $$\left|-\frac{1}{k^{4}}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)\right|\leq\frac{1}{k^{4}}$$
 which is the general term of a convergent serie. Moreover, the serie of the derivatives with respect to $y$
  is also uniformly convergent : for all $y\in\left[-1,1\right]$
 $$\left|\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)\right|\leq\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{1}{k^{2}}$$
 which is also the general term of a convergent serie. Thus we can take the derivative with respect to $y$ through the sum : we have$$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}\left(x,y\right)=-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4}}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right),$$
 $$\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x\partial y}\left(x,y\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}x\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right).$$
 But it is known that $\sum_{k}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)$
  is nowhere derivable with respect to $y$ (see for example the end of the first paragraph in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function#cite_note-7).

Now, for all $\left(x,y\right)\in\left[0,1\right]\times\left[-1,1\right]$
 , let be$$v\left(x,y\right)=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}y.$$
 We have$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\left(x,y\right)=xy,$$
 $$\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}\left(x,y\right)=y,$$
 $$\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x\partial y}\left(x,y\right)=x.$$
 Hence, we have all our second order derivatives that exist and are bounded in a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Let us compute the both integrals :$$\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x^{2}}\left(x,y\right)\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x\partial y}\left(x,y\right)dxdy=-\intop_{x=0}^{1}\intop_{y=-1}^{1}x\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4}}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)dxdy$$
 $$=-\intop_{x=0}^{1}xdx\intop_{y=-1}^{1}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4}}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)dy=-\intop_{y=-1}^{1}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4}}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)dy$$
 $$=-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4}}\intop_{y=-1}^{1}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)dy=-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{6}}\left[\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)\right]_{y=-1}^{y=1}$$
 $$=-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2p+1\right)^{6}}.$$
 where we used the Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem to invert sum and integral (the sum is uniformly convergent, thus is bounded, and any constant is integrable on a bounded domain for Lebesgue measure) and where the last inequality has been obtained like this :$$\left[\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)\right]_{y=-1}^{y=1}=\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\sin\left(-k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=2\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
 and $if k=2p$ is even, we get$$\sin\left(4p^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\sin\left(p^{2}2\pi\right)=0$$
 and if $k=2p+1$
  is odd$$\sin\left(\left(4p^{2}+4p+1\right)\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\sin\left(\left(p^{2}+p\right)2\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1.$$
 Finally, the first integral's value is$$-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2p+1\right)^{6}}=-\frac{4}{\pi}\zeta\left(6\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{6}}\right)=-\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{\pi^{6}}{945}\frac{63}{64}=-\frac{\pi^{5}}{560}.$$

Now the second integral :$$\intop_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}\frac{\partial^{2}u}{\partial x\partial y}\left(x,y\right)\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}\left(x,y\right)dxdy=\frac{\pi}{2}\intop_{x=0}^{1}\intop_{y=-1}^{1}xy\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)dxdy$$
 $$=\frac{\pi}{2}\intop_{x=0}^{1}xdx\intop_{y=-1}^{1}y\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)dy=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\intop_{y=-1}^{1}y\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)dy$$
$$=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\left[-\frac{2}{\pi k^{2}}y\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)+\frac{4}{\pi^{2}k^{4}}\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}y\right)\right]_{y=-1}^{y=1}$$
 $$=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2}}\left[-\frac{4}{\pi k^{2}}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\frac{8}{\pi^{2}k^{4}}\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]
 =-2\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{4}}\cos\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^{6}}\sin\left(k^{2}\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
 $$=-2\sum_{p=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2p\right)^{4}}+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{p=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2p+1\right)^{6}}$$
 $$=-2\zeta\left(4\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{4}}\right)+\frac{4}{\pi}\zeta\left(6\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{6}}\right)$$
$$ =-\frac{\pi^{4}}{60}+\frac{\pi^{5}}{560}.$$